# SQL Syntax incorrect, but why?

Tags: android, sql, syntax, logcat

In android, I am using database.rawQuery(command, selectionArgs);
The command I am using is

```
SELECT * FROM vocab_info WHERE name = AQA GCSE Spanish
```

The error I am getting is :

```
(1) near "GCSE": syntax error
```

But I don't know what is wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM vocab_info WHERE name = 'AQA GCSE Spanish'
```

Answer (score 3):

You should put single quotes around your string

```
SELECT * FROM vocab_info WHERE name = 'AQA GCSE Spanish'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from vocab_info where name in ('AQA', 'GCSE', 'Spanish')
```